# Where is dumped file in Google Colab?

Tags: python, file, google-colaboratory

When I wrote this code in google colab:

```
import pickle
x=10;
output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(x,output)
```

x is saved and also in another window in Google Colab I can access this file and read it but I don't know where is the file. Does anybody know where is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upload it to your Google drive:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)  

# get the folder id where you want to save your file
file = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{u'id': folder_id}]})
file.SetContentFile('data.pkl')
file.Upload()
```

This code basically fetches the data.pkl from the cloud VM and upload it permanently to your Google Drive under a specific folder.

If you choose not to specify a folder, the file will be uploaded under the root of your Google Drive.

Comment: Great. Now how do I load a file into the program to work with?

Comment: I don't understand what folder_id should be? Shoud it just be a string path to the location where you want to upload? Edit: nevermind I see now that google makes an id for each folder in your drive

Answer (score 9):

It’s in the current directory. You can also download it back to your local machine with

```
from google.colab import files
files.download(‘data.pkl’)
```

Comment: It’s not on Google Drive directory. But it’s in the current directory of the Google cloud machine, visible by calling `os.listdir(‘.’)`

Comment: Bravo! finally someone who actually *answers* the question!

Comment: how to download all files that are listed by `os.listdir(‘.’)`

Answer (score 3):

You can save and read the dumped file anywhere in your google drive folder.

```
import gc
import pickle
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

pick_insert = open('drive/My Drive/data.pickle','wb')
pickle.dump(data, pick_insert)
pick_insert.close()

pick_read = open('drive/My Drive/data.pickle','rb')
data = pickle.load(pick_read)
pick_read.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can save your pkl file by inputting this instead:

```
import pickle
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')   

x=10;
output = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/data.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(x,output)
```

and open it using this code:

```
import pickle
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

x = pickle.load(open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/data.pkl', 'rb'))
```

it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Saved dump then can be loaded from the same dir as below,

`dump(stories, open('review_dataset.pkl', 'wb'))`

`stories = load(open('review_dataset.pkl', 'rb'))`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to access the pickle files in a sub-directory (data) under the `.` directory.

> The data directory has 2 pickle files generated from the pre-processing step.

So I tried @korakot suggestion in the comments, and it worked fine!. That what I did so far.

```py
# connect your colab with the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# list the directories in the home directory
import os
os.listdir('.')

# move the sub-directory (data) into google-drive
mv /content/data/ /content/drive/MyDrive/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the pkl file using the following statements

```py
    from google.colab import files files
    files.download("model.pkl")
```

Not only pkl you can retrieve other format of data also by changing the extension